# Securely store API keys in Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api-key

How would you go around storing user's API keys in Rails app? Please note that I'm talking about being a resource provider, i.e. API keys are to my service.

Let's say we have some resource and we have 1000 API keys to it, which allow users to access this resource.

The naive way would be to store it in plaintext, but if database is compromised - all API keys are gone.

The smart way would be to store hashed and salted, but then it means that I would have to go like this:

```
ApiKeys.where(resource: '....').each do { |key| key.password == params[:api_key] }
```

Which is very time consuming (1000 hashed comparisons).

I can't do a search, since the hash is salted.

Google is kind of quiet about the issue.

Any ideas on how to implement it more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on your application requirements. Are you ever going to show a user their API key after you've generated it? If so, you'll need to either store it in plaintext or with some sort of reversible encryption.

If you're hashing and salting your API keys, your query can be simplified:

```
ApiKeys.where(resource: '....', password: hash_and_salt(params[:api_key]))
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/NKhaCnif 
Basically, you can't search unless you use the same salt everytime (otherwise - by default - same password generates different hash every time) - that was the point of question. And if salt is the same - that is insecure.  No, I'm not going to show API keys to users.

Comment: I think you might be stuck. :( Hopefully someone who knows better than I do can come along and show both of us.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can store the first few characters of the api key as plain text and store that alongside the encrypted(salted) full api key in your database.